# get a value from json array, retrive value from json object using jquery in mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can some one please help in retrieving a specific key from json?

My json object is as follows:

```
{
    "stdid": 12345,
    "stdAcntBal": "26.5",
    "stdAcntBalDue": "770.75",
    "TAmount": 0,
    "sTatus": "welcome"
}
```

How can I retrieve `studnumber` and display in textbox using jquery? Also, how can I assign this to a table tab with boootstrap?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array, but the json version of a single object.

```
{
    "stdid": 12345,
    "stdAcntBal": "26.5",
    "stdAcntBalDue": "770.75",
    "TAmount": 0,
    "sTatus": "welcome"
}
```

Usually the json response you get from your mvc action method via ajax calls  will be a  js object/value/array. You do not need to explicitly convert it to a json value using `$.parseJSON` method. You can access each property like the dictionary style syntax.

To set the value to a textbox, you can use the jQuery `val()` method.

```
var data = { stdid : 12345 , sTatus : "welcome" };
alert(data.stdid);
$("#YourUniqueTextBoxId").val(data.stdid);
```